# PJSIP video support on embedded Linux using Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, pjsip

Currently, I’m working on getting PJSIP compiled with video support on i.mx6 embedded Linux using Yocto/OE. So far I’ve succeeded in getting PJSIP with audio working.
As I understand, on Linux you have dependencies on SDL2 and FFMPEG and the Autotools configure script should manage to auto-detect all of them. 
One problem is that the configure script is not able to pick up where SDL2 is installed. Even if I enter a path using with-sdl=… I notice for example that sdl-config isn’t found, and so later on during compiling none of the SDL video device code is being compiled.
Regarding FFMPEG, does PJSIP also work with libav? I ask this question because in Yocto we already have libav included while for FFmpeg we would have to create a custom recipe.

Furthermore, because I couldn’t get the tools to automatically detect all the dependencies, I started to get "adventurous" be setting the following define statements in config_site.h myself:

```
do_configure_prepend () {
    export LD="${CC}"
    echo "export CFLAGS += -D_REENTRANT -I${STAGING_INCDIR}/SDL2" > user.mak
    echo "export LDFLAGS += -lSDL2" >> user.mak
    echo "export LDFLAGS += -lGLESv2" >> user.mak

    bbnote "enabling video support"
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO                 1" > ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_OPENGL          1" >> ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_OPENGL_ES       1" >> ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_SDL         1" >> ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_QT          1" >> ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
    echo "#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_FFMPEG          1" >> ${S}/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h
}
```

Note: I enabled/disabled the define statement independent from each other.

What I found was that:

- define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_QT: works only for iOS, enabling this doesn’t compile
- define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_OPENGL(_ES): works only for Android, enabling this doesn’t compile
- define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_SDL: gives compile error, maybe because sdl-config wasn’t run?
- define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_FFMPEG: gives compile error because of missing FFmpeg header file

So my questions are:

Any ideas why sdl2-config is not being found? Is it needed?
Can we switch FFmpeg for libav? Why? Why not?
Regarding OpenGL, even though our platform based on i.mx6 supports OpenGLES2 why can’t we use it? And why is it working on Android and not on embedded Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can make a guess why sdl-config isn't found: these project specific scripts practically never work in cross-compile situations and are typically not used in Yocto. You should use "--with-sdl" (or alternatively modify configure.ac to use PKG_CHECK_MODULES() to find sdl instead).

Why "--with-sdl" did not work for you is hard to tell (since you don't show what you tried) but assuming they want a path with prefix, I would expect this to work:

```
--with-sdl=${STAGING_DIR_HOST}${prefix}
```

STAGING_DIR_HOST is the sysroot for the system that you are currently building for: if you have libsdl in your recipe DEPENDS, it should be in the sysroot when configure runs.

Some Yocto releases have libav instead of ffmpeg, you should be able to DEPEND on the one your Yocto has and use "--with-ffmpeg" like above.

The questions about PJSIP support on linux might be worth another question -- or trying on their support forum if any exist.

Comment: Hi, well I did some trial and error, for example I've tried the following:

`--with-sdl`, `--with-sdl=${includedir}/SDL2`, `--with-sdl=${STAGING_DIR_HOST}${includedir}/SDL2`, but none got it working. I tried again with your suggestion, still the configure scripts doesn't pickup sdl2-config. I guess i'd indeed need to edit congigure.ac. However, when I try the same for ffmpeg I do see that pkg_config in Yocto is able to pick it up, in the resulting build.mak file I also see the extra CFLAGS for libavcodec etc.

Comment: Had a look at the configuration: I agree that modifying it to use PKG_CHECK_MODULES(SDL, sdl) and then adding SDL_CFLAGS and SDL_LIBS to CFLAGS and LIBS  seems like a reasonable choice: sdl-config is not going to work on yocto.

Comment: Well I just completed building PJSIP, but through another way (maybe not so clean). On my dev-pc I edited the aconfigure.ac file to use `AC_PATH_PROGS(SDL_CONFIG,sdl2-config sdl-config,,$with_sdl/bin/crossscripts)`. Next I generated aconfigure: `autoconf -o aconfigure aconfigure`. Then I fetched the pjproject sources in Yocto and copied both aconfigure and aconfigure.ac files from my dev-pc into the Yocto ${S} folder. Next, bitbake worked flawlessly. On target machine pjsua now lists H263 and H264 codecs. Video is still not working though: `!SDL_Init() error: No available video device`.

Comment: As an extra note to others who read this: I'm using Yocto 1.8, however I don't use the libav provided by oe-core. Instead I'm using a ffmpeg recipe found in newer versions of Yocto. I can conform that using the default libav is not working with pjproject and will error on : `'AVCodec' has no member named 'encode'`